# difference between 'beneath' and 'under'

Tags: prepositions, vocabulary

> And finally (since he had started looking at the inadequacies of his life, why not make a comprehensive survey?) there was his recent weight gain; a full stone and a half, so that he not only felt fat and unfit, but was putting unnecessary additional strain on the prosthetic lower leg he was now resting on the brass bar **beneath** the table.......
>   He returned to the bar to buy a third pint. Back at his table **beneath** the cupola, he drew out his mobile phone and called a friend in the Metropolitan Police whose friendship, though of only a few years’ duration, had been forged under exceptional conditions.
>   (The Cuckoo’s Calling, by Robert Galbraith)

[image]

The chart that a grammar text has drawn says that ‘*beneath*’ is under a position, making contact with underneath of something; and ‘*under*’ is lower than that. But it seems not like that way when I look up Merriam-Webster’s examples below and the above example from Galbraith's story book. I rather say that 'under' and 'beneath' are used with the same meaning.

> We had a picnic **beneath** a large tree.
>   We sat **under** a tree and rested a while.
>
> the ground **beneath** [=underneath] her feet
>   I'm wearing a sweater **under** my jacket.

Does the chart deliver wrong message or was it making sense in the past - the text was written in 1967 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the chart you reproduce is concerned I think it's misleading, there's no difference in position between *beneath* and *under* and both should be on the same level.

I would say that *beneath* and *under* are near synonyms, they both mean that something is lower than something else. The essential difference is in register.
*Beneath* is more formal, more literary. 
The choice of one over the other depends on what you want to convey.

> I'm wearing a sweater under my jacket.
>   I'm wearing a sweater beneath my jacket.

both mean that the jacket is on top of the sweater.

Some people might see a difference between:

> (1) The ground under my feet.
>   (2) The ground beneath my feet.

1) referring to the actual piece of ground my feet are touching
2) referring to the ground in general, or a larger piece of ground than just the actual piece my feet are in contact with.
I would say it is context dependent and I would use *beneath* in both cases, and maybe not *under* if I meant the ground in general.

When used in an abstract way *beneath* is preferred to *under*.

- Myrtle Wilson (in the *Great Gatsby*), married *beneath her class*.
- If I find that something is *beneath my dignity*, it means I have such a high opinion of myself hat I could not do it without degrading myself.

But:

> We have a lot of work at the moment and we are **under** great stress.

**Note:**

As in you examples I have only considered the use of both words as prepositions. But note that *under* is very rarely used as an adverb (I can't think of an example where it would be used as one - which does not mean it is impossible, of course) whereas *underneath* can.

> The garden is just under/beneath my bedroom window. (preposition - it is followed by a noun)
>   When I look out of my window I can see the garden beneath/underneath. (adverb)

Answer (score 0):

**My personal notes on this topic:** Most of this is taken from [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/below), [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/under) and [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/beneath).

[image]
[image]
[image]